# Can I just copy a git repository to Windows?

Tags: git

I'm moving a git repository from my Linux machine to a Windows machine.  I was hoping to just move the entire directory tree and find that things will "just work."  Is this the case?  Do I need to do anything about line endings?

Comment: Does the same apply to a git-svn repository?

Comment: This question is even more relevant with the arrival of bash on Windows. When I switch to bash, I realize that the git in the ubuntu environment has a completely different view (lots of untracked files) of the repository. In Windows, git sees it in a clean, all files tracked, state.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't even need the entire directory structure, just grab the .git directory and move it to your windows machine. Then run "git reset --hard" and it should rebuild the rest of the directory structure for you.

Comment: What about end-line characters, no issue there?

Comment: Yes, you need to take care of line-ending as Windows uses both, a carriage-return char and a linefeed char for newlines whereas linux uses only the latter. To handle this on windows, run 'git config --global core.autocrlf true'.

Comment: Here is a good link if are still facing problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273

Comment: awesome and super-fast! e.g. better/faster than git svn clone if you already have same elsewhere. although in that case needs git svn rebase afterwards to recreate empty directories.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you "git pull" the repo?

PS: Of course - "git clone" it (first). Point is: every git-repo is as valid as its clones.

Comment: Can you give me more detail?  I thought my options were to clone or copy; will git pull give me an identical repository instead of remote tracking branches?

Comment: Yes, of course "git clone" the repo. "git pull" would come afterwards, if you still made changes to the linux-based repo.

Comment: The problem I thought with that was getting remote tracking branches instead of real branches; it seems that when I clone to another machine, however, that doesn't happen.  So, thanks. :)