# Why adding the linker flag `-save-temps` resolves the clang-8 error: "unable to make temporary file"?

Tags: c, clang, llvm, clang++

I am using Windows + Cygwin + Eclipse +  LLVM toolchain to build a C/C++ project.

The files compile fine with `clang` C compiler, but linking with `clang++` fails with multiple `error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory`.

```
clang++ -o test "source1.bc" "source2.bc" "source3.bc" 
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory
```

Linker generates one error per each object file.

When I add the `-save-temps` option to linker, it works OK!

What could be the problem?

Adding `--verbose` gives:

```
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final) Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the `TMP` and `TEMP` variables - everything seems OK. I tried changing the `TMP` and `TEMP` to include trailing slash `/`, I also tried the whole path with backslashes `\` or forward slashes `/` - nothing helped.

Here is a more verbose outputs.

First, here is the outputs with flags `-save-temps` and `-###`:

```
 "/usr/bin/clang-8" "-cc1" "-triple" "x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus" "-S" "-save-temps=cwd" "-disable-free" "-disable-llvm-verifier" "-discard-value-names" "-main-file-name" "my_files\\my_file1.bc" "-mrelocation-model" "pic" "-pic-level" "2" "-mthread-model" "posix" "-fmath-errno" "-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-munwind-tables" "-target-cpu" "x86-64" "-dwarf-column-info" "-debugger-tuning=gdb" "-momit-leaf-frame-pointer" "-v" "-resource-dir" "/usr/lib/clang/8.0.1" "-fdebug-compilation-dir" "/cygdrive/c/my_projects/prj1/Debug" "-ferror-limit" "19" "-fmessage-length" "0" "-fobjc-runtime=gcc" "-fseh-exceptions" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" "-o" "my_files\\my_file1.s" "-x" "ir" "my_files\\my_file1.bc" "-faddrsig"
```

Here is the output without `-save-temps`, just `-###`:

```
 "/usr/bin/clang-8" "-cc1" "-triple" "x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus" "-emit-obj" "-mrelax-all" "-disable-free" "-disable-llvm-verifier" "-discard-value-names" "-main-file-name" "my_files\\my_file1.bc" "-mrelocation-model" "pic" "-pic-level" "2" "-mthread-model" "posix" "-fmath-errno" "-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-munwind-tables" "-target-cpu" "x86-64" "-dwarf-column-info" "-debugger-tuning=gdb" "-momit-leaf-frame-pointer" "-v" "-resource-dir" "/usr/lib/clang/8.0.1" "-fdebug-compilation-dir" "/cygdrive/c/my_projects/prj1/Debug" "-ferror-limit" "19" "-fmessage-length" "0" "-fobjc-runtime=gcc" "-fseh-exceptions" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" "-o" "" "-x" "ir" "my_files\\my_file1.bc" "-faddrsig"
```

So the `"-o" "my_files\\my_file1.s"` vs `"-o" ""` seems to be the difference. Is there an explanation?

Also, some more output with flags `-save-temps`, `-###`:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" "-m" "i386pep" "--wrap" "_Znwm" "--wrap" "_Znam" "--wrap" "_ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t" "--wrap" "_ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t" "--wrap" "_ZdlPv" "--wrap" "_ZdaPv" "--wrap" "_ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t" "--wrap" "_ZdaPvKSt9nothrow_t" "-Bdynamic" "--tsaware" "-o" "myexecutable" "/usr/lib/crt0.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/crtbegin.o" "-LC:/mylibraries" "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10" "-L/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib" "-L/usr/lib" "-L/usr/lib/w32api" "my_files\\my_file1.o" "my_files\\my_file2.o" " my_files\\my_file3.o" "-lnaturedsp" "-lgcc_s" "-gcc" "-lcygwin" "-ladvapi32" "-lshell32" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "/usr/lib/default-manifest.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/crtend.o"
```

and with only `-###`:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" "-m" "i386pep" "--wrap" "_Znwm" "--wrap" "_Znam" "--wrap" "_ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t" "--wrap" "_ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t" "--wrap" "_ZdlPv" "--wrap" "_ZdaPv" "--wrap" "_ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t" "--wrap" "_ZdaPvKSt9nothrow_t" "-Bdynamic" "--tsaware" "-o" "myexecutable" "/usr/lib/crt0.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/crtbegin.o" "-LC:/mylibraries" "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10" "-L/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib" "-L/usr/lib" "-L/usr/lib/w32api" "" "" "" "-lnaturedsp" "-lgcc_s" "-lgcc" "-lcygwin" "-ladvapi32" "-lshell32" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "/usr/lib/default-manifest.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/crtend.o"
```

So, again `"my_files\\my_file1.o" "my_files\\my_file2.o" "my_files\\my_file3.o"` are lost and substituted with empty strings  `"" "" ""`.

One more thing, as pointed out on the clang mailing list:
"Neither the driver option -save-temps nor the linker option --save-temps (driver option -Wl,--save-temps) respects TMP/TEMP/TMPDIR. The temporary files are saved relative to the current working directory..."

So, it's not about temporary directory location.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005867/13912132 (I know it's about git, but maybe it's the same root cause???)

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Trailing slash did not help.

Comment: Did you try to enable verbose output to get for context? What did you get? Please [edit] your question when adding new information.

Comment: @thebusybee Adding `-verbose` gives: `clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory
clang-8: error: unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory`

Comment: As I said, please add new informations to your question, don't post them here in the comments where they become lost and unread. -- If I add `-v` or `--verbose` to the call of clang++, I get a lot more of output, including the command lines of called underlying tools. But my installation might differ from yours. You might have a general problem with your system, for example missing `TMP` and/or `TEMP` environment variables or if you have them, pointing to non-existent or non-accessible paths.

Comment: What does your research on existence and rights of the path for the temporary file reveal? Did you try to find out where clang tries to create that file? Are you able to create a file at the same place?

Comment: Verbose option doesn't give too much info. Have in mind that the linking step is the problem - compiling goes OK. Also, it is the linker option `-save-temps` that helps resolve the case. However, linking with this option is terribly slow.

Comment: Tried to get more info with `-###`, maybe that helps.

Comment: This is observed in a number of places but much less attention.

Answer (score 1):

One potential cause of this failure is the `tmp` environment variable is assigned to a path that does not exist. (There may be other causes.) The error isn't tripped when the `-save-temps` argument is passed to `clang++.exe` because the temporary files are instead written to the current working directory and the branch that uses `tmp` isn't taken.

You may run into the error `unable to make temporary file: invalid argument` next. One common cause of that is having quotation marks around the path assigned to `tmp`. For example, you might have written the following in a Batch file:

```
REM  This is the quoted, fully-qualified path to this script.
set script_directory=%~dp0:~0,-1%
set script_directory="%script_directory%"

REM  clang++.exe requires a writable temporary directory.
set tmp=%script_directory%

%script_directory%\bin\clang++.exe ^
    my_program.exe ^
   -Xclang -main-file-name %script_directory%\src\main.cpp
```

In that Batch file, the script directory is quoted so that it won't fail when run from a path that contains spaces. Those quotation marks will cause an error. Don't include them when assigning a value to `tmp`.

Comment: I'm very happy with Jonathan Blow's work on moving very nearly all of this kind of configuration into the source code of the language he's been developing. Build metadata ending up in a soupy mess spread across Batch scripts, environment variables, filesystem state, and the registry leads to endless variations on this kind of cryptic "works on my machine" error.