# Cant push a Laravel application to github

Tags: git, laravel, github

I am trying to push my Laravel application to GitHub. The things I have done are as followed in the Laravel `app` directory:

```
git init
git remote add origin my@gitrepositaty.com

git commit -u 'my app'
# nothing added to commit but untracked files present

git add .
# fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in .env.example

git add origin master
# error: src refspec master does not match any
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters, when commiting a project to a repository it's good practice to commit all and only the files which are important for your project.
In the case of a laravel project you should do it from the laravel projects [root directory](http://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-root-directory).
That said, in order to commit your changes to a git repo you need to:

```
git add . # Stages your changes for next commit
git commit -m "YOUR COMMIT MSG HERE" # Commit those changes into the repo
git push # Pushes changes to your current branch (by default master)
         # and your current remote (in this case origin after you did
         # git remote add origin my@gitrepository.com
```

In general I recommend checking out [how a git repo works](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marco , when I do git add . #fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in .env.example  # comes up

Comment: @RiyanZaman few questions, which os are you using? And what did you use to edit the files (text editor, IDE, etc)?

Comment: $ git status
On branch master

Initial commit
#all the folders show in red #
Untracked files:
 
nothing added to commit but untracked files present

Comment: @RiyanZaman Ok, this problem arises because Windows uses a different character to signal line endings (\r\n instean of \n) it's all better documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467507/trying-to-commit-git-files-but-getting-fatal-lf-would-be-replaced-by-crlf-in) however in your case I recommend [configuring sublime text to use unix line endings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings), just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: That didn't help buddy .. still does not push to repository

Comment: @RiyanZaman did you already save the conflicting files again to have acceptable line endings + staged the files and tried to commit?

Comment: @RiyanZaman You may choose from using any of these two answers [Change git configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1967986/1511861) or [Convert your line endings with an external tool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15471083/1511861)

Comment: @RiyanZaman Are you still getting the fatal: LF would be replaced ... error?

Answer (score 1):

They way I fixed is was by adding autocrlf = input , safecrlf = false on the git.config file

Thanks for trying to help @ macareno.marco