# still get git LF warning for vscode taskmarks.json

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Though I executed [LF will be replaced by CRLF in git - What is that and is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important)

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

I still get

> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .../.vscode/taskmarks.json

How to really fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

See "[git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/6309)":

> The warning "`LF will be replaced by CRLF`" says that you (having `autocrlf=true`) will **lose your unix-style LF after commit-checkout cycle** (it will be replaced by windows-style CRLF).
>   **Git doesn't expect you to use unix-style LF under windows**.

(Hence the warning)

Make sure you don't have a .gitattributes directive like [`* text=auto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14232111/6309).
You can set [`core.safecrlf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coresafecrlf) to false, but not with Git 2.17/2.18: see "[Trying to commit Git files but getting: `fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF` in `<some file in repo>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15471083/6309)": you would need Git 2.19 for that.