# In GIT, is it safe change core.autocrlf to false?

Tags: git

After [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/956397) that `core.autocrlf` should be set to `false`, I would like to know if it is save to change it?

I have a repository on a server and two clients already cloned. The server is also a non bare repository but on a different branch so I can push/pull. What happens if I change the setting? Will there be problems with the next commit/push/pull?

Also who do I need to do it? Can I change it on own client and test if it's working or do I need to change it on all clients? Maybe even on the server?

Thanks for you advice!

Comment: Where did you set `core.autocrlf` to `true`?

Comment: I am using Windows on the clients and Debian server. I didn't set autcrlf. Default was true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `core.autocrlf` to `true` on Windows, and `input` on Mac / Linux. 70% of the top 300 C# repos are configured this way on GitHub. This is not the place to be hipster contrarian, your life will be far easier should you set this correctly

Answer (score 3):

For Eclipse EGit (in Windows) I have found that having it set to true can be disastrous as every time you pull it's possible that all the files get marked as changed.

Having it set to false is probably best since as long as you don't use the built-in Windows Notepad, Eclipse and Notepad++ both understand Unix line breaks.

Comment: Eclipse uses system-specific line endings by default. If you forget to change it, you'll get crap ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've never successfully modified the line ending configs and made it do what I want.  I just leave the default which is to do nothing.

Comment: Default is true in windows. Maybe it's false in linux?