# ^M characters in git commit message (git commit -v)

Tags: git, vim, line-endings

I am having a weird problem where lots of ^M characters show up in my git commit message. Please find a screenshot attached. This is not causing any problems, just makes it annoying to read through.

[image]

Tips appreciated.

Comment: "git commit message" doesn't correlate to screenshot content, title is misleading

Comment: It is my git commit -v, sorry if i was not precise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"The Proper Way", if you use Git in cross-platform environment, contrary to Abhijeet's answer, is:

**Learn and CORRECTLY configure [core.autocrlf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config) settings in each client**

Read local topic ["Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git) as good starting point

Comment: thanks, this worked! I also converted all my files to unix format, seems like the repo I forked from was developed on windows.

Answer (score 5):

Thats a windows newline. Newlines in and windows & linux are different.

You can remove it using dos2unix.

Various ways of doing it: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/

Comment: Not completely true: it is *part* of a windows newline. On windows newline is `CR LF`, on linux it is `LF` and `CR` is shown as `^M`, on mac newline is (was?) a single `CR`. There is no need to use dos2unix or similar, vim can handle this correctly if you set needed value of `'fileencodings'` option or are fine with always writing `e ++ff=dos`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows and did not want to set `autocrlf` to `true`. I worked around the issue by putting the following in my .vimrc

```
" settings for git commit messages
function GitCommitSettings()
    %s/^M//g               " remove ^M added by git diff
    syntax sync fromstart  " refresh syntax highlight after replace
    1                      " move to line 1
endfunction
au BufNewFile,BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG call GitCommitSettings()
```