# C++ comment style: /*M ... M*/, what 'M' stands for?

Tags: c++

I have seen some 3rd party source code with comments in `/*M  ...  M*/` style.  But what 'M' stands for?   (Perhaps it is used with some kind of version control, or code documentation system (like doxygen)?)

I saw it in many (if not all) source code files in opencv.

You may browse Itseez's opencv repository under GitHub by clicking
[here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv).

Oh. I forget to mention, the comment style seems to exist only in the head of the file, and it seems to declare the license.

[Example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp):

> ```
> /*M///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> //
> //  IMPORTANT: READ BEFORE DOWNLOADING, COPYING, INSTALLING OR USING.
> //
> //  By downloading, copying, installing or using the software you agree to this license.
> //  If you do not agree to this license, do not download, install,
> //  copy or use the software.
> //
> //
> //                           License Agreement
> //                For Open Source Computer Vision Library
>
> [...]
> //
> //M*/
> ```

Comment: Maybe someone thought it looked nice.

Comment: Never seen it. Can you show some of it in context?

Comment: No standard style convention (like e.g. doxygen `/** ! */`) that I'm aware of.

Comment: Update where I saw it, in the question.

Comment: A tentative to use *raw comment* as the *raw string* syntax :-)

Comment: Judging from it's use maybe "mue importante"? However it requires someone to actually search for this type of comment. Perhaps they have a inhouse tool to scan for these comments and replace the license text if they want to deliver under another license?

Comment: OS-compability problem is offtopic

Comment: Cloned repo, inspected hex-dump. 0A as EOL

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** Doesn't correlate to version control and even C++

This is a problem of cross-OS EOL-problem (Win|*Nix) and visualization of not-native EOL
`^M` (really *such* string) in [CRLF in pure-CR world and Linux|Mac GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826002/m-characters-in-git-commit-message-git-commit-v/9826436#9826436)

Example for [opengl.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3f68787051ae4f299dac6b859212134fe42d715d/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/opengl.hpp) (from your sample repo): first lines

```
/*M///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
```

are, with proper rendering

```
/*
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
```

and all glithes are results of ugly configured `core.CRLF` in author's Git (or ignoring it at all)

Comment: Nice, but why does it appear only on those two lines, not on every line?

Comment: @alain - maybe because other comments are not multiline C-style comments? OR LA is just copy-paste from foreign source

Comment: But shouldn't it be `^M` instead of `*M`?

Comment: @Black - clone repo to your *Nix, read file, ask question after it on Github (if you'll see differences in rendering) - I am not responsible for the bugs of GitHub guys

Comment: @Lazy Badger It's a pure `M`, not a `control-M`.    @black: `*` goes with `/`, since it's a comment line `/*`

Comment: @RobinHsu - it's M **in browser window** only after a lot of transformations. MISS

Comment: @Lazy Badger: It's a git repository. You can just clone it.  After that, you will  see that it's a pure `M`.   To verify it's a pure `M`, just use unix `od` utility to dump hex for the file, or use any hex editor in Windows.

Comment: @RobinHsu - I'll prefer to clone from author's repo directly (less intermediate /possible bad/nodes): on Github comments are already mangled. I'm not responsible for everybody's glitches and fiddlesticks. I can't predict where, when and how ^M became just M, but I can't see another way, than described - in the light of Occam razor

Comment: Ok. In fact, I downloaded opencv source from its official site, and it's a pure `M`.  I do post the same question at opencv forum, and some said that newer opencv source code does not follow the convention.  Perhaps, just like Skyking said: it may be just for use of a private tool.