# what does an /*M M*/ comment mean?

Tags: c++, opencv, comments, doxygen

I've noticed that [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp) uses the following comments for their license:

```
/*M
// ...
// License Agreement
// ...
//M*/
```

It clearly has nothing to do with the language itself.
I thought it might have something to do doxygen,
but I can't find any doxygen documentation for that.

What do the **M**s mean?

Comment: OpenCV [seems to use reST](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Coding_Style_Guide#writing-documentation-on-functions) for its documentation, but I don't know enough about reST to know if that's relevant

Comment: is it this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31781996/2393191