# MonoDevelop - Convert line ending dialog

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I often switch between MonoDevelop on Linux and VS2010 with the same code base so I'm forever having to click do not convert line ending.  Is there an option to set a default answer in MonoDevelop to prevent this dialog from popping up?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found it...

> Edit > Preferences > Source Code > Code Formatting > Text File > Line Endings

For v2.8.2:

> Project > Solution Options > Source Code > Code Formatting >Text File > Line Endings

And for 4 (a.k.a. Xamarian Studio):

> Tools > Options... > Text Editor > General > Coding > "Line ending conversion:"

In MonoDevelop 5.9.6 I found this option under :

> Project > Solution Options > Source Code > Code Formatting

Answer (score 5):

FYI, in MonoDevelop v2.8.2, it's located in: Project > Solution Options > Source Code > Code Formatting >Text File > Line Endings

Answer (score 2):

In MonoDevelop 4 (alias Xamarin Studio), you can find this setting in:

```
Tools > Options... > Text Editor > General > Coding > "Line ending conversion:"
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes up for warnings in Unity 2018 and MonoDevelop.

I was able to change the default, but didn't find a way to fix the warning about a file in MonoDevelop.  I ended up pasting into Atom, saving, then copy/pasting back into MonoDevelop.