# Multiplatform development and autocrlf option in Git

Tags: linux, macos, git, github, github-for-mac

I am currently using Git and all is well on my Windows PC. I have my autocrlf set to true which according to this is correct

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Actually I have no complaints, it seems to work very well, there are some warning now and again but I normally ignore them.

But what does this actually do then? Does this add CR/LF when doing a PULL and then change CRLF to LF when doing a push?

So "ALWAYS" in the repo there are files with "ONLY" LF and not CRLF?

I am about to start development in the same repository with a MAC OS X and Linux, now this is where I get confused, according to GitHub it states that for Windows set Autocrlf to TRUE.

But on Linux / MAC OS X, should I do the same? Linux I know doesn't use the CRLF.

### Update

I see various comments on Stack Overflow to not use it as true, but of course I am using 3 types of systems so I suppose this is why it's recommended here?

And Linux is recommended too? but it would never make crlf.

So I suppose the case is, always leave it as true, just in case?

Answer (score 1):

Set `autocrlf` to `true` on OS X as well. It will do the right thing. (In fact, you can also set it on Linux and it will again do the right thing.)

---

> But what does this actually do then? Does this add CR/LF when doing a PULL and then change CRLF to LF when doing a push?

Yes. It transforms files into the local native line ending format when they're checked out locally, and then when they're committed they're automatically transformed back into the canonical line ending format (`LF`).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git) might help answer some of your questions.

Basically, this only really matters if you're using an editor that cannot deal with line endings properly, or one that complains a lot (like Visual Studio).