# source tree marks all file as modified

Tags: php, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I started using sourceTree
I have a problem when I change certain files, I noticed those are files from my views folder (MVC), sourceTree marks it as:

Modified file, 1 lines changed, 1 lines removed

and when I push it to my svn the whole file is marked as changed, as in:
All the code from before my changes marked with '-'
And then all the code from after my changes marked with '+' (also stuff I didnt touch)

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the config `core.autocrlf` is set to false, to avoid automatic eol (end of lines) conversion on *all* your files.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

(and re-clone your repo to see if the issue persists)

See for more "[SourceTree App says uncommitted changes even for newly-cloned repository - what could be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15967109/6309)"

[This sourceTree thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/203422/sourcetree-files-without-changes-need-to-be-committed) points out also to `.gitattributes` files.

---

The [OP Asaf Maoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895118/asaf-maoz) points to another source ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510716/source-tree-marks-all-file-as-modified/23510814?noredirect=1#comment36235524_23510814)), still related to eol:

> the problem was in my **IDE line endings settings**, some files line endings was set to MAC (when I am not on MAC) and ST could not convert them properly.

Comment: @AsafMaoz I wasn't talking about the *local* config, but about the global one (and then re-clone again, to see if the issue persists).

Comment: Didn't help changing the config autocrlf, the problem was in my IDE line endings settings, some files line endings was set to MAC (when i'n not on MAC) and ST could not convert them properly.

Comment: @AsafMaoz Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.