# sourcetree line ending issue

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, line-endings

I am getting a very strange whitespace issue.

I am working with a local copy of a WordPress site with the .git repo in the wp-content/themes folder so all changes to any theme are tracked etc.

When I set up the repo it considered every file (apart from those in gitignore) as new files and I committed those as the 'initial commit'.

Firstly is that normal? To have to commit all the files when setting up a new repo?
2nd - and this is the strange behaviour.

when I go to stage these files I get some whitespace inserted after the first character on many of the files.

[image]

I am thinkng this si something to do with line endings. I have my global config set to autocrlf = true also I have tried

```
 autocrlf = true
 eol = native
```

In my local git config. .gitattributes is set to :

```
* text=auto
```

as advised by [Force LF eol in git repo and working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy)

Nothing is helping so far. I am working on a windows machine, but the files were tarred from a linux server and just untarred into the directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SourceTree App says uncommitted changes even for newly-cloned repository - what could be wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958446/sourcetree-app-says-uncommitted-changes-even-for-newly-cloned-repository-what)

Comment: We had this problem too, see resolutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28116468/18524

Answer (score 12):

Goto terminal and enter:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then try to stage again.

I suspect it is the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168639/git-commit-get-fatal-error-fatal-crlf-would-be-replaced-by-lf-in)

Caused by git attempts to automatically converts your line ending style to CRLF when you checkout a file and back to LF before sending it.

You can safely disable it and take care of line ending problems yourself or convert line ending style for the file in question by yourself but latter only hide the problem.

Also, you will always have to have an initial commit for each new repo, since new repo (not cloned but created with `git init`, for example) does not contain any file, therefore you will have to specify which files you would like to track by making an initial commit.

For the space after first character issue, try to fix them manually and see if the problem reappears.