# Git - cannot remove upstaged changes

Tags: git

I'm on a feature branch, and have lots of uncommitted file changes that I don't recognize. I've tried running:

```
git reset --hard head
git stash
```

But the files are still showing as uncommitted changes.

Am I using the wrong commands?

Im working on a branch that someone has changed using a mac and I am on windows so I suspect it is a line ending issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you probably have untracked files that you want to get rid of:

```
git clean -fd
```

Another (safer) approach if you think you may need those files back:

```
git stash -u
```

Comment: thanks, trying clean i get Deletion of directory '/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319' failed. Should I try again?

Comment: Are there restrictive permissions on that directory/file? Perhaps you need to manually delete it

Comment: Ive managed to delete the folder, ran both commands, which run successfully but the uncommited changes are still there

Comment: This may be a windows issue...are you using sourcetree? Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958446/sourcetree-app-says-uncommitted-changes-even-for-newly-cloned-repository-what

Comment: No im using bash, i tried in sourcetree but no luck - ill check your link out now cheers

Comment: Nothing seemed to work. I just deleted the repo and cloned it again. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Linda - :) I've seen that before and it did come to mind as I was doing it!

Comment: @DavidB Yeah, I try find the proper way to do things idiomatically in git most of the time -- but there have been situations where I just said "screw it" and cloned a fresh repo. :)