# Why is sourcetree/bitbucket/git showing files as having been changed by me when I have not changed them?

Tags: git, netbeans, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have used Netbeans for years. But just recently within the last month I started using Netbeans 11.

I started a new project where some developers use MACs, some Windows, and I think one uses Linux.
We all use different editors. I am the only Netbeans user.

We have a git/bitbucket repo that we all work together on.

The windows users such as myself use Source tree for Git/bitbucket/repo file management.
I am being told that Netbeans 11 is causing a problem for myself (and the team).

After researching the issue, I personally think it is the global git/bitbucket repo settings.
But the problem has happened several times to me since starting the project on 08/01. (And at least one other developer said it used to happen to him until he switched from one non-Netbeans editor to another. I am not quite clear if it has happened again lately to him or not.)

When I go to commit and push my changes through Source tree I see a list of files that other developers have edited/committed/pushed and I pulled in my staging area (unstaged files) as if I had changed them which I have not.
The changes are the exact same changes as the original editor/developer made. So there is nothing new—no new apparent changes—not even a slip of the keyboard on my part and an additional blank line or whatever. I don’t even recall opening said files.

So after researching this online I see that others have had similar issues.
While Netbeans was never mentioned as the culprit in these online posts, I wanted to ask here as an Atlassian developer for Source tree pointed the finger at git/bitbucket global settings.

What would you suggest I say to the members of my team who are suggesting that I need to either make a change to the way Netbeans works to stop this or use a new editor?
I prefer Netbeans. So I don’t want to change editors. I've used it for years and never had this problem before.

The project, if it matters, is a PHP, Slim framework project with some Javascript/JQuery files.
I have found this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958446/sourcetree-app-says-uncommitted-changes-even-for-newly-cloned-repository-what) and [Git/Atlassian](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/sourcetree-shows-unstaged-files-of-files-I-did-not-change/qaq-p/329327) help articles that I think speak to my personal opinion on what is causing this.
I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Locally, I have `autocrlf=true` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try again to clone and work with repository, but this time after typing:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

You can then add a `.gitattributes` file with [`text` attributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_effects) to control exactly which file you want with which eol (end of line) style.