# Is there a way in GIT, to remove files changed from being committed if it has less than 2 characters changed?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I have been working on a project and edited a bunch of files in a folder. This folder resides on my local and not watched by GIT. I usually copy the entire folder into another computer that is watched by GIT to be pushed to the repo. The problem now is that a bunch of files are being shown as changed due to line endings and spaces being shown up, as it's being copied from windows to a linux box.

I did the following command: **git diff --stat** to show all the files changed with the # of lines/characters changed.

[image]

As you can see many of these files have zero changes done to them. However, they still show up in my **git status** modified section.

How do I remove or revert these back to normal as I never changed anything with these files?

Comment: The better question is how do you get git to ignore newline changes. [Here's a Github doc on that](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is that the culprit that's causing this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git status ignore line endings / identical files / windows & linux environment / dropbox / mled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496084/git-status-ignore-line-endings-identical-files-windows-linux-environment)

Comment: `git config core.autocrlf false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more likely that these files are showing up due to mode changes.  Try running `git diff` on one of them.  Do you see something like this?

```
$ git diff query.viewport.js
diff --git a/query.viewport.js b/query.viewport.js
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

If so, then you might be able to solve this with something like:

```
$ find modules/hotsite/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -x
```

Answer (score 5):

Check your configuration on your destination Git repo in which you copy those files.

```
git config core.autocrlf
```

Make sure to set it to false: `git config core.autocrlf false` ([see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250133/6309)).

Then  double-check the presence and content of `.gitattributes` files. They can influence eol as well with [`core.eol` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309).