# Ignore whitespace in Visual Studio Code git diff view

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to ignore white-space when viewing code differences of a file (generated by GIT) in Visual Studio Code? That will be really helpful in checking for actual code additions/deletions before committing.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I believe OP is asking to ignore all whitespaces (including between words) not just trailing whitespaces.
 Unfortunately, it's still not implemented and you can track the process status here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43026

Comment: "hediet self-assigned this 3 weeks ago" please hediet, make it happen

Comment: Do you know if there is also a feature request for `diffEditor.ignoreLinebreaks`? My search for [diffEditor line break](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+diffEditor+line+break) seems to have no relevant result.

There is a comment that suggests to [add ignore line breaks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43026#issuecomment-667663662)

Comment: I created a [feature request to ignore line breaks](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/198381)

Comment: 5 years later...

Answer (score 169):

Add on your `settings.json`:

```
"diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true,
```

Comment: EDIT: I found that this setting only controls if the diff editor shows changes in leading or trailing whitespace as diffs. It does not consider whitespaces in-between the same line. I want the diff editor to ignore all the whitespace in the code, not just leading and ending whitespace of a line.

Comment: It's also available in Preferences,Settings.

Comment: doesn't affect leading whitespace

Comment: File => Preferences => Settings => Diff Editor => Ignore Trim Whitespace.

Comment: Not sure when it was added, but there's an icon to toggle this at the top of the diff document pane now.

Comment: whitespace toggle button looks like this: ¶

Comment: Use `scm.diffDecorationsIgnoreTrimWhitespace` if you want to ignore whitespace on gutter indicator. Valid values for it are `inherit|true|false`. If you set `inherit`, it will inherit from `diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace`.

Answer (score 98):

On the top right corner in diff view, there is a "Show Leading/Trailing Whitespace Differences" button (¶, called *pilcrow* or *paragraph mark*) to trim whitespace:

[image: The "Show Leading/Trailing Whitespace Differences" button in VSCode Git Diff]

Comment: fwiw, this feature was initially added in VS Code [1.20.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_toggle-for-ignore-trim-whitespace-in-the-diff-editor) by the commit [`8c91f01fda90388138414d414ace2b230d3331c8`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/8c91f01fda90388138414d414ace2b230d3331c8) .

Comment: Perhaps be the accepted best answer nowadays, though the OP asked the question years ago. Thank you!

Comment: This button is only available when you are checking a revision, not during a merge

Answer (score 4):

One idea is to format the documents using the same formatting standard and then compare the files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32371165)

Comment: This does actually answer the question, and pretty well IMO.

Answer (score 4):

If you are searching for a solution that doesn't bluntly ignore all whitespace changes, but only those that don't have an effect on your code, you should look into semantic/structural diffs. They use the grammar rules of the programming language to distinguish whether a whitespace is relevant (e.g. within a string) or optional (e.g. between function arguments).

I had a similar issue and ended up developing my own extension (SemanticDiff) that adds a structural diff mode to VS Code. Here is an example how it ignores whitespace changes:

[image: Ignored whitespace changes]

You can get the extension from the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=semanticdiff.semanticdiff). I am not aware of any other VS Code extension that implements such a feature.

Outside of VS Code, there are a few more options available, such as [difftastic](https://github.com/Wilfred/difftastic) or [diffsitter](https://github.com/afnanenayet/diffsitter).

Comment: Correct, there are plenty of online tools as well and even offline like WinMerge