# master warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF messages on git push

Tags: git, github

Every time I push to github from my windows machine I see these messages:

```
C:\G\ab>git commit -m "Added new breadcrumb code"
[master warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in WebUserApp/content/less/body.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in WebUserApp/content/less/html-light.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in WebUserApp/content/less/top.css.
```

Can someone tell me what is causing these and how I can fix (if it needs to be fixed) the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `autocrlf` option in your git config to **false** or **input**.

You can set the option when you edit your `.git/config` file in the global section or you use the git command line

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/
[Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git)