# Where are the git settings stored when installing git on windows?

Tags: git

Where are these settings stored in windows 8?

[image]

Not in 
C:\Users\[user]\.gitconfig

apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are store:

- in the git installation folder itself (`<git>\etc\gitconfig`): system config
- in `%HOME%\.gitconfig` (global config), and id you are using [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat), `HOME` is set to `%USER_PROFILE%`
- in your local repo (.git/config)

Note that you need to define core.autocrlf yourself because `<git>\etc\gitconfig` defines it by default to true.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

(and while there are [cases where `core.autocrlf` can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/6309), I prefer setting it to false and [working with `.gitattributes core.eol` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309))

Answer (score 0):

Try using running `echo $HOME` in "git bash", it should give you its home directory (which might be what you're looking for).