# All lines removed from file and all lines added to file in commit

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I'm looking at a commit (in Bitbucket) and for a given file which is, let's say, 100 lines I see that there are 100 lines removed, and 100 lines added. The content of the lines removed and the lines added are identical down to the indentation and spacing.

Under what circumstances can what I just described occur?

Comment: Probably the line ending changed (e.g. from `\n` to `\r\n` or vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if this is an end of line issue, try:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git clone https://bitbucket.org/user/repo newLocalClone
cd newLocalClone
git status
```

(while there are [cases where `core.autocrlf` can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/6309), I prefer setting it to false and [working with `.gitattributes core.eol` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309))

Comment: I agree with you VonC, but on the other hand I am a big opponent for this particular git feature. IMHO line endings is not something your VCS should take care of it. I personally think you as a developer and you as team should take care of it. E.g one could configure the IDE to use a common line ending. For me personally this is policy I declare when I work with other team mates. Just an addition to your answer, anyway you get +1.

Comment: @ckruczek " line endings is not something your VCS should take care of it": I agree, and that is why I set this global config to false. The `core.eol` in `.gitattributes` have always been enough for me.

Comment: Yep, agreed on that. I just had a the experience with some tools like egit, which where not capable of handling the `.gitattributes`, in particular the `core.eol` etc, correctly which resulted in biiiiigggg errors and bugs.

Comment: @ckruczek good point. I just saw https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342372#c42 yesterday... this doesn't look promising.

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I mean. For a software developer this is actually [unacceptable](https://importantshock.files.wordpress.com/2008/08/unacceptable.png?w=455&h=562)... Thx for the positive discussion ;)

Comment: Thank you all for the answer, the links, and good discussion. Much appreciated.