# Does using EditorConfig affect how I should configure Git for line endings?

Tags: windows, git, line-endings, editorconfig

There are lots of questions here about handling line endings in Git. However, one question I haven't seen addressed is whether using [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) has any implications for how Git should deal with line endings.

I ask because virtually all projects I work on have an `.editorconfig` that sets `end_of_line` to `lf`. This is fine with me, but the standard advice for setting Git's line-ending handling in Windows is to set `autocrlf` to `true` (ie. convert to CRLF on checking out).

In this situation, Editorconfig and Git seem to be pulling in opposite directions (Git will convert line endings to CRLF on checkout, but then Editorconfig will presumably convert them back to LF whenever a file is saved). So I'm wondering if the use of Editorconfig makes the best practice with line-endings on Windows different?

**Note:**

My inclination is to defer to Editorconfig and add a `.gitattributes` file containing `* -text` (ie. tell Git not  to touch line-endings, regardless of `autocrlf` setting) to every project that has an `.editorconfig` file that specifies line endings for the project (I know for a fact that everyone working on these projects uses Editorconfig and/or is using an OS that uses `lf` endings, and this seems to avoid the irritating line-ending conversion warnings that Git often seems to spew out in Windows). The problem is, despite lots of reading on the topic, line-endings in Git continue to baffle me, so I'm not confident that the above won't introduce new issues (a previous experiment with `.gitattributes` ended up breaking image files). So: does this make sense as an approach? Or does Editorconfig have no bearing on line-ending handling best practice?

Comment: May I ask what the original line endings of the source files in the repository are?  By the way, @VonC [recommends against](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git) setting `autocrlf` to true except in special cases.

Answer (score 3):

Set `autocrlf` to `false`.

While it was useful in the past for source control tools to handle line endings, it really is an editor problem and it was solved with EditorConfig.

Answer (score 2):

> seen addressed is whether using EditorConfig has any implications for how Git should deal with line endings.

It should not have any effect on git since git check the config values when you stage content and when you commit it.

Git will checkout and commit content in the defined way.
The only way this tool can effect your code is to update the working directory content with the defined CRLF based upon the configuration you supply.

> The problem is, despite lots of reading on the topic, line-endings in Git continue to baffle me, so I'm not confident that the above won't introduce new issues

You are not the only one who find it hard to understand how git CRLF works. In your case i don't see any reason to be worried and regarding your question:

> So I'm wondering if the use of Editorconfig makes the best practice with line-endings on Windows different?

I would have define all my configuration in the `.gitconfig/.gitattributes` and leave out the CRLF from being handled outside of git.