# Line endings with git, insisting warning

Tags: git, line-endings

I have just started using git with windows. Each time I add a file I get this warning

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in main.cpp.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

and it seems like the way to surpress this is

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

and then I can add my file without warnings. But I could not find a permanent solution to this, so do I need to do  git config --global core.autocrlf true each time before I do a git add ?? Is there a permanent way to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git)

Comment: Look into modifying your `gitattributes` file.

Comment: In what way is `git config --global core.autocrlf true` not permanent?  Do you have something else changing the configuration back?