# Unable to fix eol whitespace issue in git

Tags: git, windows-7, github, msysgit

I have a [repository](https://github.com/lscharen/fluentmigrator) on guthub that is a fork of [fluentmigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator).  This was my first foray into git and I've gotten myself into a situation which I am unable to clean up some whitespace conflicts between my fork and the upstream repository.

I am running on Windows 7 and am using the msysgit client.  Here are the linked repositories

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/lscharen/fluentmigrator (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/lscharen/fluentmigrator (push)
upstream        http://www.github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator (fetch)
upstream        http://www.github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator (push)
```

My local repo is current with my github repo and has some changes against the upstream repo

```
lscharen@LSCHAREN01 /c/checkout/fluentmigrator (master)
$ git diff --stat origin/master

lscharen@LSCHAREN01 /c/checkout/fluentmigrator (master)
$ git diff --stat upstream/master
 src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs      |  563 ++++++++++----------
 .../Initialization/IRunnerContext.cs               |    1 +
 .../Initialization/RunnerContext.cs                |    1 +
 src/FluentMigrator.Runner/MigrationLoader.cs       |  193 ++++----
 src/FluentMigrator.Runner/MigrationRunner.cs       |    4 +-
 src/FluentMigrator.Runner/VersionLoader.cs         |  343 +++++++------
 .../Versioning/VersionMigration.cs                 |  221 +++++----
 .../Unit/TestVersionTableMetaData.cs               |  105 ++--
 .../Unit/VersionLoaderTests.cs                     |  272 +++++-----
 .../Infrastructure/DefaultMigrationConventions.cs  |  252 +++++-----
 .../Infrastructure/MigrationMetadata.cs            |   91 ++--
 src/FluentMigrator/MigrationAttribute.cs           |   70 ++--
 .../DefaultVersionTableMetaData.cs                 |   84 ++--
 .../VersionTableInfo/IVersionTableMetaData.cs      |   57 ++-
 14 files changed, 1182 insertions(+), 1075 deletions(-)
```

The changes in some of these files are pure EOL issues.  If I look at the diff for `src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs` and ignore whitespace.

```
$ git diff --stat -w upstream/master src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs
 src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs |   13 ++++++++++++-
 1 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

I've attempted to fix the problem by following the advice on setting `core.autocrlf` from various SO answers, but nothing seems to put me in a state where my file is updated and shows a diff against my `origin`, but matches the `upstream`.

Here is what I've tried.

**Set `core.autocrlf input` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck) answer**

```
$ git rm --cached src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs
rm 'src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs'

$ git config core.autocrlf input

$ git add src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs

$ git diff --stat upstream/master src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs
 src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs |  563 +++++++++++++------------
 1 files changed, 287 insertions(+), 276 deletions(-)
```

**Set `core.autocrlf false` and manually convert with dos2unix**

```
$ git config core.autocrlf false

$ dos2unix src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs

$ git diff --stat upstream/master src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs
 src/FluentMigrator.Console/MigratorConsole.cs |   17 ++++++++++++++---
 1 files changed, 14 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Close! But there are hanging `^M` characters at the end of each inserted line in the diff, e.g.

```
+        public string Group;^M
```

Setting `git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol` made the `diff` look correct, however I'm afraid that if I commit this file that I'll still be putting incompatible whitespace characters into the repo.

I'm trying to fix up my fork for a pull request, so any advice in general for dealing with this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would redo the local clone entirely by:

- `git config --global core.autocrlf=false`
- `git clone https://github.com/lscharen/fluentmigrator`

In short, no EOL conversion should have taken place in the first place, and you should been `dos2unix` all your files right now.