# How to have Git store CRLF in index

Tags: windows, git, newline, git-svn

I use `git-svn` at work and people are constantly complaining that I'm committing `LF`'s instead of `CRLF`'s. (We're mostly a Windows shop).

As far as I can tell, when `core.autocrlf` is `true` the working copy is `CRLF`, when `false` it's `LF`, and when `input` it's left untouched. I like the `autocrlf = true` as a concept, but I wish it would default to `CRLF` in the index since that's what get's committed to SVN.

**Is there a way to set what line ending the index uses?**

I've seen `core.eol`, but this also seems to only set what the working copy uses, not the index.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add a file named `.gitattributes` to the root of your project. This will force everyone to commit same line ending. In you case, as you want to force `crlf`, you'll add this line in the `.gitattributes`:

```
* text eol=crlf
```

Then, you can also normalize every files in your repo once, and never bother about it again: [Trying to fix line-endings with git filter-branch, but having no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273)

You can also refer to github guide on line ending: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: Can I do this without a `.gitattributes` file? Maybe a `.git/info/attributes` file instead? (Since I'm using `git-svn`)

Comment: Yes, you can also put this setting in this file and have the same effect (only for you).

Comment: You can checkout the section on file precedence on the git documentation: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html

Comment: ok, I'm having trouble with the `git diff ... | xargs...` line. It says `xargs: argument line too long`. I'm not sure I want to make that many changes anyway...

Comment: I don't think this even answers the question - the docs say this is just like setting `core.autocrlf = true` but only on certain files (in  this case only text files, so it's absolutely no different).

Comment: By specifying `*`, you take every files. And by text files, they mean not `binaries` files, and not _only_ `*.txt`. Also, setting `autocrlf` to true will always commit files as ending in `lf`, that's why we manually set them to be `crlf`.

Comment: For `eol=crlf` it says `This setting forces git to normalize line endings for this file on checkin and convert them to CRLF when the file is checked out.` To me this means that it's still normalizing to `LF` in the index (vague as it reads) and convert to `CRLF` in the working copy. But I want it to normalize to `CRLF` in the index. Is that even possible?

Comment: You can test it out. `git diff` will point out if there's changes to the line-ending. If it's not working, then just set `core.autocrlf` to false and Git won't change line-ending anything automatically; this will work as long as every developer is on windows.

Comment: It seems the person asking the question wants to store CRLF in the index. This does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `git-svn` uses the `svn:eol-style` property from SVN to decide how to store the line endings. If you go into a pure SVN checkout & add `svn:eol-style` set to `native`, Git will use CRLF for Windows and LF for Linux/OSX.

I also have these settings:

```
$ git config core.autocrlf false
$ git config core.safecrlf true
```

I don't have anything in my `.gitattributes` file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but just in case someone is still looking for an answer...

First, you have to make sure that `core.autocrlf` is `false` in your global and local config.
Then to force git to convert to CRLF, you can use a [filter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#filters_b) defined like this :

In your local `config` file (.git\config) :

```
[filter "crlf"]
        clean = unix2dos
```

And you can use it by adding a filter for certain files in the `attribute` file (.git\info\attributes) :

```
*.txt filter=crlf
```

This filter makes use of the command [unix2dos](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/dos2unix.htm) which comes with Git for Windows and could already be available if you are on Linux. Otherwise, you can [install it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117623/how-to-install-dos2unix-on-a-ubuntu-app-on-a-windows-10-machine) or use an alternative command like `sed -i -e 's/\r//g'` (this command works well assuming that you don't have any Mac line endings in your files).

---

What about running the filter on all files like this?

```
* filter=crlf
```

This could work, but I haven't used it in a large repo, so I can't guarantee that it won't affect performance or that there is no risk of corrupting binary files.

Luckily, `unix2dos` has some checks in place to detect binary files and won't make any changes to them if they are detected as binary. I tried to run it on a PNG and got:

```
unix2dos: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 2
unix2dos: Skipping binary file fff.png
```

You might need to keep an eye open if some files aren't detected properly, however.