# How to force git commit with CRLF?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

If I use `autocrlf`, it looks like here

```
                     push    clone
1) true:             x -> LF -> CRLF
2) input:            x -> LF -> LF
3) false:            x -> x -> x
```

but I want git auto commit with CRLF:

```
x -> CRLF (if I use LF, it will commit with CRLF)
```

Can I do it?

Thank in advance !!!

Edit: I think git doesn't support it, so I force change `lf` to `crlf` with [crlf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crlf).

Comment: You had accepted the right answer, and always use core.autocrlf=false .  You should always use a .gitattributes directive to limit the eol change to a set of files. core.autocrlf would apply indiscriminately to all files. Don't.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692773/how-to-have-git-store-crlf-in-index/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at least make sure the file are checked out correctly, with a [`eol` directive in a `.gitattributes` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking_out_and_checking_in):

```
# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf
```

> This setting forces Git to normalize line endings for this file on checkin and convert them to CRLF when the file is checked out.

That, combined with `git config --global core.autocrlf false` would make sure your files are usable in your working tree.

---

> I want when I commit file with CRLF or LF, git change it to CRLF.

With the setting above, that does not seem to be possible, as the default normalization being always to convert of LF on checkin.
That only is to make sure your files are checked out with the right eol (end-of-line).

But if you want to force crlf on checkin, you will need to do so manually.
Try:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Make sure you do not have any `core.eol` or `text eol` directive in any .gitattributes files (to avoid any "renormalization")

And do a [**`unix2dos`**](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/dos2unix.htm) on any file checked out with the wrong eol.

Finally, add and commit: those files with CRLF should still be checked in with CRLF.

Comment: It just work if i use CRLF, my mean is :I use LF and commit auto change to CRLF.
Thank you.

Comment: @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ so do you mean my answer is the opposite of what you want?

Comment: I want when I commit file with CRLF or LF, git change it to CRLF.

Comment: @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I used  "core.autocrlf false" before I ask this question, but use "unix2dos" is good idea.
So I use module node crlf.
Thank you for good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some module to change `LF` to `CRLF`.

But I think you don't need change it, just use `autocrlf=true`