# copy .git from Linux to Windows `Changes not staged for commit`

Tags: android, git

env:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Windows 7

I copy the .git directory of Android goldfish kernel repo from Ubuntu to Windows, result in `git status` is:

```
# On branch android-goldfish-2.6.29
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Documentation/io-mapping.txt
#       modified:   arch/ia64/scripts/check-gas
#       modified:   arch/ia64/scripts/toolchain-flags
#       modified:   arch/powerpc/boot/wrapper
#       modified:   drivers/mmc/core/sdio_io.c
#       modified:   include/linux/earlysuspend.h
#       modified:   include/linux/mmc/sdio_func.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_connmark.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_dscp.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ecn.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_mark.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_tcpmss.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_tos.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ttl.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_mark.h
#       modified:   include/linux/wakelock.h
#       modified:   net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ecn.c
#       modified:   net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ttl.c
```

But I haven't modefied any fiels, and `git checkout -- .` doesn't work, it still prompt the information. So what's the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to copy paste .git folder. Setup git again in ubuntu or windows where you want to copy the code. Add remote origin and pull your code first. If you don't have remote origin then first push your code in some remote repo like github or bitbucket. I also did it with my projects.

Answer (score 0):

The modification must be by the end of line, differ in windows and linux.

When you are using [GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) this process is automatically. But commit this changes should not affect your project.

You can read more about it on  [github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)
eventually, you can use the solution that [exposes](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#re-normalizing-a-repository), this solution was response in  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273)

Comment: I have diff, not the end of line.  Thanks!

Comment: several git repos have the same problem.