# Why is the following command inconsistent in my repository?

Tags: macos, git

In my repository, which has mixed line endings.
I am using Mac OS X, and git 1.8.3.1

I would like to renormalize this repository so that every file has line endings that agree with the .gitattributes file.

To this end, I have checked out the latest change:

```
git checkout origin/develop
git reset --hard
git rm -rf .
git rm --cached -rf .
rm .git/index
git checkout HEAD .gitattributes
git reset --hard
git status
```

Now, `git rm --cached -rf .` will cause an error, but I am being very paranoid with the above command. (On my machine, those commands were on one line, ignoring exit codes)

I repeat the command many times. (Ie, UP; ENTER; UP; ENTER; UP; ENTER;...)

Most of the time, I have a clean check out, which is not what I am expecting.

However, roughly once every ten times, I find that  I get three files (which seem to be correctly renormalized).  The remaining times there is no renormalization.

The output of such a file that gets renormalized (Ie, is 'modified') is:

```
$ file source/RemoveDuplications.cs
source/RemoveDuplications.cs: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) C++ program text, with CRLF line terminators
```

My git attributes file has a fair number of entries, but the relevant one is here:

```
* text=auto
*.cs text eol=crlf
```

What might be going wrong here?

Comment: I should point out that the files that show up as modified, are the same ones that show up modified if I do: `find . -iname '*.cs' -exec unix2dos '{}' \;`

Comment: Clearly, git's normalisation does not always happen, and I am confused.

Comment: This bug still occurs with git version 1.8.4, from homebrew.

Comment: Do you have any other `.gitattributes` with concurrent eol directives? Is your `git config core.autocrlf` set to `false`?

Comment: @VonC: Yes, I originally only put up the line for the *.cs one, then I realised I should put all potentially conflicting lines in the order they appear - the .gitattributes file did get added to a non-normalized repository about a dozen commits ago, and the repository was not normalised.  There was an attempt to normalize it with the new .gitattributes, but due to this issue, it was not normalized adequately.

Comment: Can you point me at a repository URL I can clone the project from? Happy to take a look.

Comment: @MatthewMcCullough: Sadly no, however the moment I get some time I will very much want to replicate this issue in test repository; So thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Did you ever get a test repository put together?

Comment: Can you share any stderr output from the sequence of commands?

Comment: I have made no progress with this question - should I delete it?  The issue has not appeared again so it must have been a fluke?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are doing may be overly complex. You shouldn't need to remove all files from the repo or delete the index by hand. Have you tried:

```
git rm --cached -r .  # remove everything from the index
git reset --hard      # replace files w/ corrected line endings
git add .             # stage all changes
git commit -m "Normalize line endings"
```

If this isn't working for you I'd re-check the values of your [`core.autocrlf`](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#global-setting) and `.gitattributes`. You may need to clear those, reset your shell, check out the repo again and then reset them to get the behavior you want.

Here are some other resources that might help:

- [Github - dealing w/ line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)
- A [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck) with multiple answers to consider
- A [good post](http://blog.gyoshev.net/2013/08/normalizing-line-endings-in-git-repositories/) about the pros/cons of this approach vs git filter-branch

Comment: Matt: I wanted to fix the line endings in the repository itself, not just the working copy.

Answer (score -3):

You could always use something like a sed script to edit the files and then recommit them to see if this keeps happening.  If you do this from the command line, you should, using the proper regex, be able to pull out any hidden characters that might be causing your problem.