# Changing branches in git results in changed files

Tags: git, branch

When I am switching between branches in git, I am seeing that files are changed even though no updates have been made.  This has just started happening recently.

```
$ git status
# On branch dev
nothing to commit (working directory clean)


$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'


$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   App.Core/ViewModels/CriteriaViewModel.cs
#       modified:   App.Core/ViewModels/UserManagement/AccountTagsViewModel.cs
#       modified:   App.Core/ViewModels/UserManagement/TagViewModel.cs
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

These *are* files that I changed on the dev branch, but then added and committed.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing that would cause this?

Comment: This is particularly strange because you cannot switch branches unless your changes are committed or stashed. Is nothing happening after the switch to `master`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns - Nothing that I am aware of.

Comment: Can you close VisualStudio, do ``git clean -f -x -d`` and repeat the switching?

Comment: Can you provide a `git diff` and also check if `git diff -w` produces any output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the difference is in the eol (end of line) characters in those "changed" files.

If it is, make sure your core.autocrlf is set to false:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

That would avoid any automatic conversion on checkout.

See "[git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/6309)" for more.

If you need to enforce a consistent eol, use `.gitattributes` directives, as in "[Fixing the line-endings in a Git repository using the `.gitattributes` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21833574/6309)".

Comment: Marking this as the answer.  It seems to have fixed it.  Thank you!