# CRLF issue when running Django via Vagrant on Windows 7

Tags: django, git, bash, virtual-machine, vagrant

I am using Vagrant and Oracle Virtual Machine to run a Django project on Windows. The problem is that when I try to execute one of the file, I've got an error:

```
-bash: /url_to_my_file: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've already Googled for the problem is here what was tried:

1) At Git Bash:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.eol lf
git config core.eol lf
```

2) At Vagrant SSH Git:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
git config core.autocrlf input
git config --global core.eol lf
git config core.eol lf
```

3) Added .gitattributes to Git project main folder:

```
* text eol=lf
```

4) Used dos2win to convert all files inside Vagrant VM (desparate measure):

```
find . -type f \! -path \*/\.svn/\* -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Still no result... may be someone can help with this?

Comment: the Ctrl-M is the Windows carriage-return char. If `bash` is complaining about it, you need to process the script that is being run with `dos2unix scriptWithCtrl-M_Error`. Keep a backup of your original just in case ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your files are already checked in with 'CRLF` line endings.

You might need to [normalize the line endings in your repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511273/537554).

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511273/537554).

Comment: The answer in the link solved the problem. After 2 days of struggle it finally works.. thank you!