# Git - Windows AND linux line-endings

Tags: linux, windows, git, ubuntu, line-endings

My main OS is windows 10.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 box running in Vagrant that I develop my applications on. The box is running SMB which gives me root file access to the Ubuntu server.

On the Ubuntu server I have my application files in a GIT repo with a gitlab server as the origin.

I run SourceTree on my windows machine that connects to the ubuntu GIT repo through the SMB share (so I assume it uses my Windows GIT installation).

Git status on the ubuntu machine gives no changes.

Git status on Windows and SourceTree indicate that all the files have changed (because of the line endings).

What settings on which OS should I use in order to be able to use the same local repo on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1511273/1327005

Comment: Not a duplicate. Following their exact instructions still gives the exact same result. git status clean on ubuntu, all files modified on Windows/SourceTree. Problem here is that I use the exact same repo working copy on 2 OS'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On Windows:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

On Linux:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Read more about [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-all)

Comment: This gives the same result... git status on linux gives empty result, git status on windows shows all files as modified.

Comment: `$ git config --global core.autocrlf input` was enough for me on Windows too.

Comment: beautiful! This worked for me. I was trying to share repo b/w windows and wsl, stored in windows FS.

Comment: This works great for wsl, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Set the `autocrlf` to the desired value:

**How `autocrlf` works**:

```
core.autocrlf=true:    core.autocrlf=input:      core.autocrlf=false:

       repo                     repo                    repo
    /        \               /        \              /        \
crlf->lf    lf->crlf     crlf->lf       \          /            \      
 /              \        /                \      /                \
```

**Yet another way to show how `autocrlf` works**

```
1) true:             x -> LF -> CRLF
2) input:            x -> LF -> LF
3) false:            x -> x -> x
```