# Identify files with difference line endings on local vs remote

Tags: git

**UPDATE: Compared with the suggested SO thread there are no warnings. There are files in my repo which are not in remote and I was looking for a way to identify every file in local which is not in remote due to possible incorrect line ending issues**

I have a file in local master and it's not found in origin/master, looks like it's ignored due to line endings.

For example when I modified the file and tried to commit/push, I got an error

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in assets/js/main.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

I tried `git config core.fileMode false` to force it to ignore line ending and followed the solution here [Can't fix line endings issue on git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630952/cant-fix-line-endings-issue-on-git) but it didn't help

**Is there a way to discover all of the files on local which are NOT in origin/master due to this line ending mismatch?**

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it's not found in origin/master" ? what thing do you look at to establish that ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. It's not ignoring the file, it's ignoring the differences in line endings used for purposes of determining if the file has changed.

Comment: A warning is not an error. I move past this one regularly. Why didn't your configuration work? That's the key.

Comment: [`core.fileMode`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corefileMode) is not about line endings at all.

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk helped answer it yes, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

As per Vasiliy's suggested SO thread [Git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

I did the following:

- Set the **core.autocrlf** to **true** (most often used method which converts automatically so people on Windows and Mac machines can work on repo files together)
- Re-added all the files to repo with renormalize setting: **git add . --renormalize**
- This time it detected changes so I was able to commit and push